# Scala: Passing Any to a method which takes java.lang.Object

Tags: scala

I'm confused on how Scala's `Any` relates to `java.lang.Object`. I know that in scala, `AnyRef` corresponds to `object`, but it seems to make a difference whether the method (which takes `java.lang.Object`) is defined in a java class or a scala class):

the java class:

```
public class JavaClass {
    public static void method(Object input)  {
    }
}
```

the scala application:

```
object ScalaObject extends App{

  def method(input:java.lang.Object) = {}

  val a:Any = null

  method(a) // does not work

  JavaClass.method(a) // does work
}
```

So if the method is in a java-Class, then the compiler allows me to pass a variable of type `Any`, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler tries to "make up" for the difference between Scala's and Java's type systems. In Scala, `Object =:= AnyRef` (they're aliases) and `AnyRef <: Any`. Therefore, a Scala method that takes `Object` or `AnyRef` cannot take an `Any` or an `AnyVal`. If you wanted a method that worked on everything, well, then you would have written `Any`, right?

However, *Java* methods that take `Object` are normally meant to work on *all* values, whether they be actual `Object`s or primitives (`int`, `long`, etc.), and they work due to the boxing conversion of primitives into `Object`s. Primitives and `Object` do not have a common supertype like they do in Scala. The Java type system is not expressive enough to differentiate "I only want actual objects," from "I will take anything, be they object or primitive."

Therefore, the Scala compiler patches this up by turning Java methods of `Object` into methods of `Any`. This feature is simply to ease interop between the languages. It won't apply this transformation to Scala code though, because if you wanted that behavior then you would have actually written `Any` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is that `Any` can be either `AnyRef` or `AnyVal`, while `method` can only accept objects which are `AnyRef`. If you modify the `a` type to be `AnyRef`, it is going to work:

```scala
def method(input: java.lang.Object) = {}
val a: AnyRef = new Object
method(a)
```

In case of calling the static Java method, the Scala compiler will turn `Any` into `Object`, which also includes boxing of `AnyVal` values.